# Cross Tab Report Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

mytable:

[image]

and result i want:

[image]

but i can't query do you help me?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please share few more details like Table structure, sample data , SQL fiddle but not images  and also please let us know what you have tried to solve this :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your requirement you want pivoting of your data.

Try this:

```
select tmn_code,
       max(case when bank_type=1 then totalamount end) as bank_1_total_amount,
       max(case when bank_type=1 then totalpay end) as bank_1_totalpay,
       max(case when bank_type=2 then totalamount end) as bank_2_total_amount,
       max(case when bank_type=2 then totalpay end) as bank_2_totalpay
from your_table group by tmn_code;
```

Comment: select tmn_code,
       max(case when bank_type=1 then totalamount else 0 end) as bank_1_total_amount,
       max(case when bank_type=1 then totalpay else 0 end) as bank_1_totalpay,
       max(case when bank_type=2 then totalamount else 0 end) as bank_2_total_amount,
       max(case when bank_type=2 then totalpay else 0 end) as bank_2_totalpay